# Android relations between functions

Tags: android, android-studio, ontouchlistener

Now I have been searching for how to get Touch X and Y and what I found is :
1.I can implement the OnTouchEventListner and use the implemented method
2.I would override the OnTouchEvent method then get the X and Y from the (event)
3.another way is to use my RelativeLayout View and use its OnTouchListner 
and all of these solutions give the same result and all are working.
**NOW** the question is :
                WHAT IS THE RELATION BETWEEN THESE SOLUTIONS ?
AND WHAT IS THE CONCEPT THAT I DON'T KNOW ?
I wanna be able to understand how to use these ways without searching for each one alone and memorize the code each time I type something new

Comment: what do you plan to do with the x and y you obtain?

Comment: if you want to learn you don't need to memorize the code. You need to understand the function of it. They're giving ideas that will help you to achieve your goal. If you don't want to learn each one, then its up to you. And you don't even give any function of your x and y, how can we have an idea on that?